# MQTT and Bee nodes

Tags: node

I'm like to use MQTT to communicate with my Bee node. I've read that the MQTT protocol have been implemented inside the bee-node service. I use the [0.1.0 release](https://github.com/iotaledger/bee/releases/tag/v0.1.0) of Bee.

When I start my node I've got the following errors in warn.log file :
`2021-05-17 22:26:58 bee_node::plugins::mqtt::manager ERROR Disconnecting mqtt broker failed: PahoDescr(-3, "Client disconnected").`
`2021-05-17 22:26:58 bee_node::plugins::mqtt ERROR Creating mqtt manager failed Mqtt(PahoDescr(-1, "TCP/TLS connect failure")).`

My config.toml file contains
`[mqtt]`
`address = "tcp://localhost:1883"`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

Informations given on Discord by Thibault Martinez [IF]
So, you are not doing anything wrong at all. It just turns out that the MQTT library we were using is just not good enough to allow us to provide all required node features. We are currently switching the MQTT library to another one and that will be released in a new bee version that hopefully will come soon.
Unfortunately, the state of MQTT in Rust is just not satisfying yet.